# Access to variable value from another class in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

ClassA.h

```
...
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *myVariable;
- (id) setMyVariable:(NSString *)string;
- (id) getMyVariable;
```

ClassA.m

```
...
@synthezise myVariable = _myVariable;
... some inits
- (id) setMyVariable:(NSString *)string {
   _myVariable = string;
   NSLog(@"here nslog success return new value: ", _myVariable);
   return _myVariable;
}

- (id) getMyVariable {
   NSLog(@"here nslog return nil", _myVariable);
   return _myVariable;
}
```

ClassB.m

```
#import ClassA.h
...
ClassA *classA = [[ClassA alloc] init];
[classA setMyVariable:@"some"];
```

ClassC.m

```
#import ClassA.h
...
ClassA *classA = [[ClassA alloc] init];
NSLog(@"here nslog returns nil: @%", [classA getMyVariable]);
```

Why does `[ClassC getMyVariable]` return nil? Same result when I try to set value directly without setter and getter. I already read other topics on StackOverflow and Google, but have not idea why it doesn't work.

Comment: Because in ClassC, you create a new object classA. So is not myVariable is not set for this one.

Comment: You didn't call the setMyVariable method, only the getMyVariable, so the variable was never given a value, hence it's nil.

Comment: Larme, You right. Now i see that. May you support me and say how i may get that variable without alloc new instance?

Comment: Bedford, i call getMyvariable at ClassB.m and want to get value from ClassC.m

Comment: It probably doesn't work because this is just crazy code.

Comment: Popeye, I make it crazy when try to do this) So, now i know about my logical mistake. For this task i need use Notification method for send new states between views.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. What you may need to look at is called a singleton design pattern, please see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your whole code is a bit of a mess really. Why are you using a weak property? Why are you using a `@synthezise` since this is is automatically done by xcode for you along with the getters and setters so you don't need to create them ever.

The reason why your `[classA getMyVariable];` is nil in `ClassC` is because you create a new instance of it on the line above. By the looks of what you are trying to do is you want to set the variable for instance of a class in one class and access that variable on the same instance in a different class. So one method of doing this is to use a singleton, these are sometimes not liked but I think they work well and don't see a reason why some (not all) developers don't like them.

So lets do some cleaning up and try implementing a singleton

**ClassA.h**

```
@interface ClassA : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *myVariable;
// No need for you to create any getters or setters.

// This is the method we will call to get the shared instance of the class.
+ (id)sharedInstance;
@end
```

**ClassA.m**

```
#import "ClassA.h"

@implementation ClassA
// No need to add a @synthezise as this is automatically done by xcode for you.

+ (id)sharedInstance
{
    static ClassA *sharedClassA = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        // If there isn't already an instance created then alloc init one.
        sharedClassA = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    // Return the sharedInstance of our class.
    return sharedClassA;
} 
@end
```

Right so we have cleaned our `ClassA` code up and added a method for getting a shared instance of `ClassA` so now to `ClassB`

**ClassB.m**

```
// Other code in ClassB

// Get the shared instance
ClassA *classA = [ClassA sharedInstance];
// Set the value to the property on our instance.
[classA setMyVariable:@"Some String Value"];

//........
```

Now that `ClassB` has set the variable we can go to `ClassC` now and look at it.

```
// Other code in ClassC

// We still need to have an instance of classA but we are getting the sharedInstance
// and not creating a new one.
ClassA *classA = [ClassA sharedInstance];    
NSLog(@"My variable on my shared instance = %@", [classA myVariable]);
//........
```

Might help if you read [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/46988/ios-design-patterns) and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) for help on understanding different design patterns

Comment: For all you question i may answer: because in my stupid books say use that. I only start learn Objective C. Today is 4'th day since i first install xcode. So now i stupid idiot and that is normal for this time. I will be better. And you answer take me more information, keywords for learn very more. Very thanks for you. All work perfect now. I learn how it works and go next. Thanks!

Comment: With Singleton Pattern you open me new world. Second thanks! I remove a lot of garbage code with new pattern. It made me happy

Answer (score 1):

because you don't set a value after creating an object. i should be like this:

```
ClassA *classA = [ClassA alloc] init];
[classA setMyVariable:@"some"];
NSLog(@"not nil anymore: @%", [classA getMyVariable]);
```

BTW: the @property tag provides two keywords to set getter and setter methods.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic, getter=myVariable, setter=setMyVariable:) NSString *myVariable;
```

and apple avoids the word "get" in getter-methods...

Comment: I dont need to set value in `ClassA`. But i may do this. I need to set this value in `ClassB` and after some time get this from `ClassC`.

Comment: Thanks for getter and setther methods. Did not know about them. Four of my books is outdated.

Comment: maybe your question was not very clear to me. i think you need to share the object of class A with class B and C. if you create a new object, it's another instantiation.

Comment: You right. I need share myVariable value from all of this classes. And i dont know how i may do that without initiate new instance. In more information: ClassA is controller, ClassB is ViewB controller. When user do some action in them ClassB set value of myVariable. Then ViewB change to ViewC, where i need get value of myVaribale, which already sets from ViewB.

Comment: -1 because you don't seem to actually answer the question of being able to access the variable in another class after being set in a different class. Also why have you done `getter=myVariable, setter=setMyVariable:` what is the point in this, and if you want to do anything with this an not lose it you will need to change from `weak` to `strong` otherwise it will be lost.

Comment: i'm new here, i will learn about how to answer correctly. thanks for your criticism, but i think i answered the question in the text: "Why does [ClassC getMyVariable] return nil?"
your point with weak to strong is correct.

Comment: The best thing to do would be just to make the suggested amendments to your answer then I will be more then happy to remove my -1